# how to set en EditText to both password and numeric keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I've the following EditText which it's characters need to be hidden as it is a password. I can do this with the following.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Please Enter Password/Pin"
        android:inputType="textPassword"

         >
```

I would like to set the keyboard to numeric as all passwords are numbers, but when i do the following the numbers are displayed. How can i acheive both?

```
passwordPin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        passwordPin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved.**

```
android:inputType="textPassword|number"
android:password="true"
```

Comment: android:password is deprecated: Use inputType instead

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
android:inputType="textPassword|number"
```

Comment: Ravel Thanks, i couldn't find it

Comment: @Ravel Hi i've just tested it and i'm afraid that you can see the characters when entered into the password field. How can i make them hidden. The keyboard part is fine.

Comment: @turtleboy it is the part of emulator or device . we can not do anything to it.

Comment: Hi i've found a solution and posted an answer. You just need android:password="true" in there as well. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the following line for `EditText`

```
android:inputType="textPassword|number"
```

Comment: hi, the keyboard is numeric but the edittext is no longer hidden characters. You can see the characters

Answer (score 2):

Looking through Eclipse, you can also use the following, not sure how backwards compatible it is however.

```
android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically as long as password is now deprecated. Try this:

```
passwordPin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
passwordPin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same requirement and solved it this way:

In XML:

```
android:inputType="number|numberPassword"
```

Programmatically:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER || InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
```

Hope this helps :D